# Class has no initializers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm getting this error, but I don't know how to fix it

```
class GameView2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var player1ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var player2ScoreLabel: UILabel!

    var selectedPlayer: Int!
    var currentPlayerMove: Int
    var previousPlayerMove: Int!
    var player1Score: Int
    var player2Score: Int
```

Comment: you need an init() method to fill out the currentPlayerMove, player1Score and player2Score since they are neither optional nor implicitly unwrapped optionals

Answer (score 4):

In swift all non-optional stored properties must be initialized, either inline or in an initializer.

In your class there are 6 optional properties (all defined as implicitly unwrapped, the ones ending by `!`) and 3 non optional properties (`currentPlayerMove`, `player1Score` and `player2Score`). You should either initialize them inline:

```
var currentPlayerMove: Int = 0
var player1Score: Int = 0
var player2Score: Int = 0
```

or in an initializer, or make them optional, or make them implicitly unwrapped optionals:

```
var currentPlayerMove: Int!
var player1Score: Int!
var player2Score: Int!
```

and initialize **before using them** - a good place is `viewDidLoad`:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentPlayerMove = 0
    player1Score = 0
    player2Score = 0        

    ...
}
```

Some guidelines:

- use a normal optional if the property can be nil
- use implicitly unwrapped optional if the property is supposed to be not nil, but you can't initialize inline or in an initializer - **warning**: accessing implicitly unwrapped when it's nil causes a runtime exception, always be sure to initialize properly before use
- use non optional if the property is supposed to be not nil, and you can initialize either inline or in an initializer - **this should always be the preferred solution instead of implicitly unwrapped, when possible**